# MDX/SSRS - how do you get the "ALL" label to display in a report

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a very simple MDX example which will return my Freight measure by month and rolled up as ALL

```
  SELECT NON EMPTY
    { 
    [Measures].[Freight]
    } on columns
    ,
    NON EMPTY {
    [Due Date].[Calendar Month].members
    } on rows
    FROM [Adventure Works Cube]
```

[image: table results]

Now using the same MDX in SSRS the ALL label does not appear.
[image]

Is it possible to have the ALL label appear in the report?

If you can display it in the report, is it possible to rename it to something like YTD?

Comment: Hello John, did the accepted answer solve your original issue - `Is it possible to have the ALL label appear in the report?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to rename it in the MDX:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD] AS 
    [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All] 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Freight]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD]
     ,[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Cube];
```

Comment: Hello. The original issue OP was facing was that the `All` label was not appearing in the report. In your experience, have you every faced this? My best guess is OP is using `[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].members` instead of  `[Due Date].[Calendar Month].members`. What do you think?

Comment: @SouravA possibly - lets wait for feedback from user

Answer (score -1):

it's possible in SSRS to rename your fields in the dataset properties. You can even add calculated fields (with the add button in the top left corner). Hope this helps.

[image]